# Two step regression - should we account for 'consumed' degrees of freedom?

Tags: regression, linear-model, degrees-of-freedom, frequentist

One approach to determine whether the relationship between an exposure (x) and outcome (y) is linear is to use a flexible model with smoothing spline terms, such as a generalized additive model (GAM). These GAMs often reveal that the functional relationship between variables is approximately linear. In this case, one could go on to fit a regular linear regression model to access regression coefficients and 95% confidence intervals.

The process is then 1) fit a GAM 2) if the GAM supports linearity, refit the model using a standard linear regression model to access coefficients (and 95% CIs).

I'm not sure if there are problems with this approach. In particular:

1. Will the 95% CI's and p values from the linear model have appropriate frequentist coverage properties, seeing as we've used the data itself to identify the appropriate model?
2. Should we/can we  account for the degrees of freedom consumed by the GAM model in the subsequent linear regression model?